# How do I insert new first page into IOS App?

Tags: ios

I don't know if it is just that my brain is not working but I am stuck on this.

I have an old IOS 4 app with a Tab Bar as a root view controller.

In IOS 4 through 6 I had a view that covered the entire window until the user had logged in  but in IOS 7 that view gets moved ABOVE the tab bar.

So: I want to add a new view that gets seen before the tab bar gets loaded and returned to when the user logs out.

Only thing is - I can't seem to figure out how to add a view controller to the main window which already contains the TabBar.

I know that this must be really simple but could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why don't you keep the tab bar controller as the root controller and simply present the login screen as a modal view controller from the tab controller? When the user logs in you dismiss the login controller.

Comment: The app is a bit more tricky than that - but you put me on the right track. Thank you.